# How to hook into event fired from grandchild control?

Tags: c#, wpf

Consider a hierachy like the following:

```
Parent Grid -> Detail Grid -> Detail of Detail Grid
```

Where each contains the grid following it. Now, I want to fire an event from Detail of Detail Grid. I've set up my handler and events as follows.

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent DetailofDetailVmClickedEvent =
   EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("DetailofDetailVmClicked", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(RepoBreakdownRecordControl));

public event RoutedEventHandler DetailofDetailVmClicked
{
   add { AddHandler(DetailofDetailVmClickedEvent, value); }
   remove { RemoveHandler(DetailofDetailVmClickedEvent, value); }
}

public void RaiseDetailofDetailVmClickedEvent()
{
   var args = new RoutedEventArgs(DetailofDetailVmClickedEvent);
   args.Source = MyDetailOfDetailGrid.GetFocusedRow() as DetailofDetailVm;
   RaiseEvent(args);
}

private void MyDetailOfDetailGrid_OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   RaiseDetailofDetailVmClickedEvent();
}
```

I want to handle this at the `Parent Grid` level. Since I can't hook directly into the `Detail of Detail Grid` event handler (as `Parent Grid`, `Detail Grid`, and `Detail of Detail Grid` are all their own controls), how can I accomplish this?

I will happily admit I'm probably having a brainfart from lack of coffee, but such is life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh. Time for some coffee.

I just needed to add the following to `Parent Grid`'s constructor.

```
public ParentGridControl()
{
    AddHandler(DetailOfDetailGridControl.DetailofDetailVmClicked, new RoutedEventHandler(DetailofDetailVmClicked_Handler));
}

private void DetailofDetailVmClicked_Handler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
   // do things here
}
```